# Can i shorten this?

Tags: c#

Hello i need som help to shorten this down all answers are appreciated!
i have trid to find some ways but no success and i am kinda noobish so something simple maybe but not to simple

```
        if (comboBox11.Text == "")
        {
            comboBox1.Enabled = true;
            comboBox2.Enabled = true;
            comboBox3.Enabled = true;
            comboBox4.Enabled = true;
            comboBox5.Enabled = true;
            comboBox6.Enabled = true;
            comboBox7.Enabled = true;
            comboBox8.Enabled = true;
            comboBox9.Enabled = true;
            comboBox10.Enabled = true;
            comboBox11.Enabled = true;
            comboBox12.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            comboBox1.Enabled = false;
            comboBox2.Enabled = false;
            comboBox3.Enabled = true;
            comboBox4.Enabled = false;
            comboBox5.Enabled = false;
            comboBox6.Enabled = false;
            comboBox7.Enabled = false;
            comboBox8.Enabled = false;
            comboBox9.Enabled = false;
            comboBox10.Enabled = false;
            comboBox11.Enabled = true;
            comboBox12.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: Hint: instead of having 12 different variables, could you create an array or a list?

Comment: If you are using WinForms and these controls are all hosted in the forms Controls container you can set the enabled property with a loop

Comment: If you cannot use an array or a list, like Jon Skeet mention, you can use reflection.

Answer (score 3):

In a Winforms application these controls are all hosted inside a control container. Usually this is the form itself and you can loop over this control container to get each combo in this way

```
bool enable = (comboBox11.Text == "");
foreach(ComboBox cb in this.Controls.OfType(ComboBox)())
    cb.Enabled = enable;
// These are always enabled.
comboBox11.Enabled = true;
comboBox3.Enabled = true;
```